# Is there any way of hide Navigational items in community upon User Profile?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, partner-communities, javascript-controller

I have been asked to hide tome tabs from navigation bar on Partner Community when the logged user is Community User.

What have investigated so far:

Create a custom theme and replace the the layout in community.
This takes me to build this logic:

Lightning Component controller to retrieve the element that has the index of the tab item in this case the tag is this:

```
<a class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" data-menu-item-id="1" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="6:51;a">Employers</a>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the element this way

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    // Returns a collection

    var y = document.querySelectorAll("li a[data-menu-item-id=\"0\"]"); 
    // I'm not sure what does this return

    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("ddisplay", none); 
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);

    // Get the user id, I can work with and an Apex method to get
    // the Profile Name
    component.set("v.userId", $A.get('$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id'));
}
```

})

To setAttribute("display",none);

I don't now what else to do, I looked for a setting to do this but nothing, also how much effort can this take to get it properly done?

Comment: Its not recommended to use document methods in your lightning component as you are doing. you can refer to [Using JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_intro.htm?search_text=component.find) from the developer documentation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could make your life easier by using a [page variation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) and simply use a different header component based on that.

Comment: I have tried what you say in every way as much as I can but I still can't manage to change the navigation bar according to the user's profile. I'm using Partner Central template if it help to troubleshoot my issue. I would appreciate a lot if can give me more details about how to please, my brain is about to explode. Thanks a lot in advance.